# Behavior of $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^x \frac{1}{n}$

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I plotted the function

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^x \frac{1}{n}$$

in Wolfram Alpha over $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and it gave me some unexpected behavior for negative $x$. This function is obvious for $x\in\mathbb{N}$. Can anyone explain how Wolfram Alpha is computing this? Is the plot below a numerical artifact or is there some function on $x\in\mathbb{R}$ that agrees with $f(x)$ when $x\in\mathbb{N}$?

[image]

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sum+1%2Fn+n%3D1+to+x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extension of the sum from integers to reals uses the Gamma function, which has poles at the negative integers.

See the last equation on the page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29#Relation_with_Gamma_Function

Answer (score 2):

If you [just enter the sum without plotting it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20sum%201/n%20n=1%20to%20x), you'll see that Mathematica has produced an analytic closed form for it.

We can consult [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) to learn more about the digamma function.

There is surely some uniqueness theorem, although I have no experience with them. I imagine it is something like that is unique analytic closed form for your sum that is both increasing and concave down on the positive reals.